# Libuv: protecting the event loop from concurrent accesses

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, libuv

I would like to know what precautions are needed to be able to safely add callbacks to a `libuv` event loop from multiple threads in C++.

**More details**

I have some multi-threaded C++11 code that I want to modify to use make use of `libuv`'s network communication API. I do not want to create a new `libuv` event loop every time network communication is required (for that would use up resources). So I created a `libuv` loop in a separate thread (I prevent the loop from closing by registering a "keep-alive" timer). This event loop is currently passed to other threads using a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern#1008289). Callbacks are then registered (from other threads) while the loop is running.

I am worried about concurrent accesses to the `libuv` event loop when registering new callbacks: when calling `uv_tcp_init` the loop is explicitly passed (rather, a pointer to the loop); when calling `uv_tcp_connect` the loop is not explicitly mentioned but a pointer to it is stored in the `uv_tcp_t` struct passed. I haven't checked whether any of the above-mentioned functions actually modify the loop, but my intuition is at least one of them must do to (otherwise, `libuv` couldn't keep track of active handles).

My first thought was to add a `mutex` attribute to the singleton used to access the event loop and use it to prevent concurrent access to the event loop when calling any of the above functions:

```
EventLoop & loop = EventLoop::get(); // Access the singleton
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(loop.mutex_attribute);
    // Register callbacks, etc
}
```

However, this does not protect the event loop from concurrent accesses between my thread (which successfully acquired the lock) and some `libuv` internal function (or a registered callback triggered by `libuv`) since the latter are not aware of my using a singleton to protect access.

Should I be worried about said concurrent accesses? What steps may I take to mitigate the risks?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I settled for was to not add handles directly to the `libuv` event loop from other threads, but rather to have other threads add handles to a queue (stored in the same singleton as the pointer to the event loop). Access to the queue is protected by a `mutex`.

The "keep-alive" timer then periodically empties the queue (the timer callback is aware of the `mutex` protecting the queue) by:

- getting the first handle from the queue,
- registering that handle with the `libuv` event loop (since we register the handle from a callback within the `libuv` event loop, there shouldn't be any risks of concurrent access), and performing any other operation needed on this handle (in my case, call `uv_tcp_init` and `uv_tcp_connect`),
- repeating until the queue is empty.

Comment: You could write to a PIPE when a callback is added from another thread to trigger a callback in the main thread (which will then add the callbacks from the queue)